# raspberry PI Operating Temperatures

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3

In the Raspberry PI FAQ it states this for the operating temperature range:

*The Raspberry Pi is built from commercial chips which are qualified to different temperature ranges; the LAN9512 is specified by the manufacturers as being qualified from 0°C to 70°C, while the AP is qualified from -40°C to 85°C.*

I have a silly question -- what is the AP?  Does that refer to the WIFI Access Point or something else?

Any help is appreciated!
Brian

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming as defined in this [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There's a specialized [RPi Stackexchange site](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why don't you ask them..?

Answer (score 0):

With further research, I found an answer.  They are talking about the application processor.

Answer (score 0):

It has simple meaning as: access point.